# Intuition behind Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, intuition, bayes-theorem

I am having a hard time developing an intuition behind Bayes' Theorem. I have asked this question with the help of the question below only because I was not able to get the right words to put in my question.

> A bag contains 10 balls some of which are white and others are black. A person draws 6 balls and finds that 3 are black and the other 3 are white. Find the probability that the number of black balls in the bag are equal to the number of white balls.

I have already solved the question using Bayes' Theorem to get the answer as $10/33$. However I am confused as to why the solution below is invalid:

---

I already have 6 balls out from the bag. For satisfying my required condition, I need to have 2 black balls and 2 white balls in my bag.

Sample space $(S) =\{wwww,wwwb, wwbw, wbww, bwww, bbww, \ldots\}$

$$n(S)=  16 $$
$$n(E)= 6$$

$$P(E)=6/16$$

---

This solution seems to be invalid. However, I am not able to get a concrete logic as to why this happens. Please provide me with some arguments.

Comment: If I had the power, I'd delete every single question containing the word  "intuition".

Comment: Nowhere in the problem does it say there are only $10$ balls in the bag. It says there are $10$ white balls and some number of black balls.

Comment: @ProfessorVector i'm interested, why would you do so?

Comment: @Alan Intuition ("the power or faculty of attaining to direct knowledge or cognition without evident rational thought and inference" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition) can't be explained by definition, it can only be acquired by exercise. Emphasis: by *doing* exercises, not by watching them done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuitively, why does Bayes' theorem work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210175/intuitively-why-does-bayes-theorem-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are comfortable computing the actual answer $\frac{10}{33}$ for yourself,
I can confine my response to an intuitive explanation of why your alternative
analysis is invalid.

When you divided your sample space into 16 elements, the distribution was

1. 4 w's : 1 element
2. 3 w's : 4 elements
3. 2 w's : 6 elements
4. 1 w   : 4 elements
5. 0 w's : 1 element

You then (in effect) **assumed** that the proportional relationships between the 5
possible distributions is

$$ 1 ~\text{to} ~4 ~\text{to} ~6 ~\text{to} ~4 ~\text{to} ~1. $$

Given the constraints of the problem, and the required method in computing the
accurate answer of $\frac{10}{33}$ the actual proportional relationships between
the 5 possible distributions is

$$\binom{3}{3} \binom{7}{3} ~\text{to} \binom{4}{3} \binom{6}{3} ~\text{to}
\binom{5}{3} \binom{5}{3} ~\text{to} \binom{6}{3} \binom{4}{3} ~\text{to}
\binom{7}{3} \binom{3}{3} $$

$$ = 35 ~\text{to} ~80 ~\text{to} ~100 ~\text{to} ~80 ~\text{to} ~35. $$